# ASP.NET Regular Expression needed for checking valid DB DataType of Money

Tags: asp.net

Hey Looking for a regular expression which I can use to check for valid DB types of Money.

I.e. Examples

9.8600
11.5400

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d+.\d{4}
```

Would match the two examples you give.

```
Regex.IsMatch("11.5400 ", @"\A\d+.\d{4}\Z");
```